# How to convert csv to R's xts object?

Tags: r, datetime, xts

Does anyone have an idea on how to convert this to xts R object?

```
#format: symbol,interval,date,time,open,high,low,close,,
# cat test.csv
AD.F,5,20141008,093500,0.8736,0.8738,0.8732,0.8733,0,0
AD.F,5,20141008,094000,0.8732,0.8736,0.8731,0.8735,0,0
AD.F,5,20141008,094500,0.8736,0.8737,0.8733,0.8737,0,0
AD.F,5,20141008,095000,0.8736,0.8747,0.8736,0.8746,0,0
AD.F,5,20141008,095500,0.8746,0.8748,0.8742,0.8743,0,0
AD.F,5,20141008,100000,0.8744,0.875,0.8742,0.8747,0,0
AD.F,5,20141008,100500,0.8747,0.8747,0.874,0.8745,0,0
AD.F,5,20141008,101000,0.8744,0.8744,0.874,0.8743,0,0
AD.F,5,20141008,101500,0.8744,0.875,0.8744,0.875,0,0
AD.F,5,20141008,102000,0.8751,0.8752,0.8746,0.8751,0,0
```

I tried `read.csv()`, but I have a problem with the time format (`read.csv` converts time to number,  eg from "091500" to 91500).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can specify that the date and time columns are to be treated as character using `colClasses`.  This also processes the index.  If there are multiple values in column 1 then it will split each into separate columns:

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo("input.csv", sep = ",", split = 1, index = 3:4, tz = "", 
      format = "%Y%m%d %H%M%S", colClasses = rep( c(NA, "character", NA), c(2, 2, 6)))
```

This can be converted to xts via `as.xts(z)` .  See the help file on `read.zoo` and the zoo vignette `Reading Data in zoo` for more info.

Alternately, use the same `colClasses` with `read.table` .